# Mdns discovery problem on 3G modem (TP_LINK) using swift

Tags: swift, macos, modem, 3g, mdns

So I've been working on an IoT project for some time now. But I've been facing a weird problem lately. I have a mdns software of avahi-daemon 0.6.23, a Linux card with version of 2.6.35.3-571 and gcc version 4.4.4 (4.4.4_09.06.2010) connected to my device.

My main purpose is to find mdns broadcasts on the network and get device ip's from these. When I am connected to a TP_LINK 3G modem I am unable to discover my device with the specs I've added on the first part. But when I check from Discovery I see the mdns broadcast and I face no problems on adsl modems. My initial idea was that it was because of the specific model of the modem. But I've tried it on several different models and it seems like it always fails on 3G modems.

I'm currently using swift and to discover wiced services I am using NetServiceBrowser. And I use searchForServices(ofType: "_services._dns-sd._udp", inDomain: serviceDomain) for scanning.

I'm stuck and have not been able to find any solutions or reasons to why this is happenning. Any ideas are really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've also encountered with this issue years ago, exact versions were different but problem was same. We couldn't find any solutions at that time.